# Compatibility of 802.11a/b/g with 802.11n

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

The specs on my tablet device says

> Wi-Fi 802.11b/g

and I'm about to buy a new wireless router with specs that say the following about its WiFi version, and nothing else:

> Wireless-N, 2.4 GHz

Will my 802.11b/g tablet be able to connect to my soon-to-be-bought wireless router?

Answer (score 3):

Wireless N is completely different than Wireless A, B, or G. They are not the same. If your tablet does not explicitly say that it supports Wireless N, then it doesn't support Wireless N. 
However, many routers and Wireless Access Points will include A/B/G and N. Even though they are different standards based on IEEE 802.11, they can work together.

Comment: b/g/n support is more common than a/b/g/n support due to a using the 5ghz range. Without knowing more specifics about @Kit's hardware, it's impossible to say, but I would find it hard to believe that a new wireless-N router would lack at least G support.

Answer (score 2):

If your wireless router doesn't support 802.11b or 802.11g, no. Having said that though, there are few n routers that don't support at least g, but you should check the full specifications to be certain.